# Sustituir ENTER por TAB en formularios HTML con JS

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

He observado que hay usuarios que prefieren utilizar la tecla ENTER para pasar de un campo a otro de un formulario en vez de la tecla TAB. Entiendo que por inercia de otras aplicaciones.

Me gustaría sustituir ENTER por TAB en formularios HTML haciendo uso de JS.

Para ello, he probado el siguiente código, pero no funciona:

```
<form>
  <input autofocus />
  <input />
  <div>
  <textarea ></textarea>
  </div>
  <input />
  <select>
    <option>48</option>
    <option>57</option>
    <option>92</option>
  </select>
  <input />
</form>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();

      var tabEvent = new Event('keydown');
      tabEvent.key = 'Tab';
      tabEvent.keyCode = 9;
      tabEvent.shiftKey = event.shiftKey;
      tabEvent.altKey = event.altKey;
      tabEvent.ctrlKey = event.ctrlKey;
      tabEvent.metaKey = event.metaKey;

      document.body.dispatchEvent(tabEvent);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Esta otra opción da mejores resultados pero, al llegar al `<textarea>` o el `<select>`, se queda quieto y no continúa:

```
<form>
  <input autofocus />
  <input />
  <div>
  <textarea ></textarea>
  </div>
  <input />
  <select>
    <option>48</option>
    <option>57</option>
    <option>92</option>
  </select>
  <input />
</form>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input','textarea','select');

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();
        var nextInput = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (!nextInput) {
          nextInput = inputs[0];
        }
        nextInput.focus();
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia de cosas que pueda probar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que para tomar el siguiente elemento usas `this.nextElementSibling;` el cual toma el hermano del elemento actual ¿Pero, y si el hermano es un `div`?

Tienes que tomar el siguiente elemento de la lista `inputs[i+1]`, pero para que funcione correctamente hay que hacer algunas otras correcciones.

- Cambiar `getElementsByTagName` por `querySelectorAll` para que tome en orden los elementos
- cambiar `var` por `let` dentro del `for` (gracias @
  infinit3Loop__)
- En lugar de `index+1` usar `(index+1)%inputs.length`, de esta manera cuando llega al ultimo elemento (da la vuelta) y sigue con el primero
- Cambiar `keyup` ´por `keydown` de lo contrario los `select` se abren y el focus pasa al `option` por lo que no toma el siguiente elemento

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();
        inputs[(i+1)%inputs.length].focus();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input autofocus />
  <input />
  <div>
  <textarea ></textarea>
  </div>
  <input />
  <select>
    <option>48</option>
    <option>57</option>
    <option>92</option>
  </select>
  <input />
</form>
```

---

Aquí otra variante, respetando el atributo `tabindex`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select')).toSorted((a,b) => a.tabIndex  - b.tabIndex);

  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();
        inputs[(i+1)%inputs.length].focus();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input autofocus />
  <input tabindex="2" />
  <div>
  <textarea tabindex="4" ></textarea>
  </div>
  <input />
  <select tabindex="3">
    <option>48</option>
    <option>57</option>
    <option>92</option>
  </select>
  <input tabindex="1" />
</form>
```

---

*Nota: Cambiar este comportamiento puede tener problemas de usabilidad para personas con alguna discapacidad*

Comment: Adicionalmente podría usar 'let' en lugar de 'var' dentro del for y ya no tendría que definir la variable 'index', ya que se estaría creando un ámbito de bloque para cada iteración del for, cada una con el valor correcto de 'i'.

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ Toda la razón, gracias por el comentario

Comment: @Yuseff no hay porque!

Comment: Va genial, ¡muchas gracias a ambos!